# Query Kusto data from C#

Tags: c#, azure-data-explorer

I am trying to access the Kusto data from C# App using kusto library, has the below working code but want to check is there any better/optimal way like directly get results in json instead of 1) looping thru schema table 2) building a data table with schema and 2) finally getting the values from reader.

```
 var table = new DataTable();
            string query2 = "StormEvents | take 2";
            string cluster2 = "https://help.kusto.windows.net/Samples";

            using (var client = Kusto.Data.Net.Client.KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider($"{cluster2};Fed=true"))
            {
                var reader = client.ExecuteQuery(query2);
                DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();

                if (schemaTable != null)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
                    {
                        table.Columns.Add(row["ColumnName"].ToString(), row["ColumnType"].GetType());
                    }
                }
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var row2 = table.NewRow();
                    for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        row2[i] = reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal(table.Columns[i].ToString()));
                    }
                    table.Rows.Add(row2);
                }
            }

             string resultTable = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following program outputs the same format, but is (in my opinion) simpler when the expected output schema is known in advance:

```cs
const string query = "StormEvents | take 2";
const string clusterUrl = "https://help.kusto.windows.net";
const string databaseName = "Samples";

var connectionStringBuilder =
    new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(clusterUrl, databaseName)
    .WithAadUserPromptAuthentication();

using (
    var queryProvider = KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider(
        connectionStringBuilder
    )
)
{
    var results =
        queryProvider
        .ExecuteQuery(query)
        .ToEnumerable<MyClass>() // `MyClass` is defined below
        .ToList();

    string resultTable = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
    // do something with `resultTable`
    // ...
    // **Note**: it's _not_ always required (nor efficient) to serialize
    // it as JSON - but this was presented as a requirement in this 
    // specific question.
}

// The query's output schema matches the fields in this class
// in terms of order and data types.
class MyClass
{
    public DateTime StartTime;
    public DateTime EndTime;
    public long EpisodeId;
    public long EventId;
    public string State;
    public string EventType;
    public long InjuriesDirect;
    public long InjuriesIndirect;
    public long DeathsDirect;
    public long DeathsIndirect;
    public long DamageProperty;
    public long DamageCrops;
    public string Source;
    public string BeginLocation;
    public string EndLocation;
    public double BeginLat;
    public double BeginLon;
    public double EndLat;
    public double EndLon;
    public string EpisodeNarrative;
    public string EventNarrative;
    public JObject StormSummary;
}
```

or, if the output schema isn't known in advance, you could try this instead:

```cs
...

using (var client = KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider(connectionStringBuilder))
{
    var jObjects =
        client
        .ExecuteQuery(query)
        .ToJObjects();

    var resultTable =
        new JArray(jObjects)
        .ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);

    // do something with `resultTable`
    // ...
    // **Note**: it's _not_ always required (nor efficient) to serialize
    // it as JSON - but this was presented as a requirement in this 
    // specific question.
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  when i try to use the client.ExecuteQueryAsync method , its complaining that  "Taxk<IDataReader> does nto contain a definition for ToObjects".Could you please let me now what I am missing here ?

Comment: that sounds like a generic C# programming question - one answer to it is provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-task)